# Настройка кодировки на sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx, битрикс

Доброго времени суток знатоки!

Я настраиваю sphinx на битриксе. Все сделал по инструкции, но он не ищет товары на сайте. Проверял все - сам сфинкс работает на сайте. Но когда полез в логи запросов сфинкса, то обнаружил, что там вместо русских слов - каракули. Пытался по всякому менять кодировку - не помогает. Вот конфиг файл сфинкса:

```
source lsParentSource
{
type = mysql
sql_host = 127.0.0.1
sql_user = user
sql_pass = 
sql_db = bookcity
sql_port = 3306
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query_pre = SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF
}

source books : lsParentSource
{
sql_query      = \
  SELECT * \
  FROM b_search_content
}
index bitrix
{
#main settings
    type = rt
    path = C:/OpenServer/domains/www2/sphinx/data
    docinfo = inline
#choose appropriate type of morphology to use
    #morphology = lemmatize_ru_all, lemmatize_en_all, lemmatize_de_all, stem_enru
    morphology = stem_enru, soundex
#these settings are used by bitrix:search.title component
    dict = keywords
    prefix_fields = title
    infix_fields=
    min_prefix_len = 2
    enable_star = 1
#all fields must be defined exactly as followed
    rt_field = title
    rt_field = body
    rt_attr_uint = module_id
    rt_attr_string = module
    rt_attr_uint = item_id
    rt_attr_string = item
    rt_attr_uint = param1_id
    rt_attr_string = param1
    rt_attr_uint = param2_id
    rt_attr_string = param2
    rt_attr_timestamp = date_change
    rt_attr_timestamp = date_to
    rt_attr_timestamp = date_from
    rt_attr_uint = custom_rank
    rt_attr_multi = tags
    rt_attr_multi = right
    rt_attr_multi = site
    rt_attr_multi = param
#depends on settings of your site
    # uncomment for single byte character set
    charset_type = sbcs
    # uncomment for UTF character set
    #charset_type = utf-8
   }
   indexer
{
    mem_limit               = 32M
 }

searchd
{
log = C:/Sphinx/data/log/searchd.log
query_log = C:/Sphinx/data/log/query.log
read_timeout = 5
max_children = 30
pid_file = C:/Sphinx/data/log/searchd.pid
seamless_rotate = 1
preopen_indexes = 0
unlink_old = 1
}
```

Кодировка самой базы - utf8_general_ci. Может кто-нибудь помочь разобраться с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение! Долго пришлось над этим помучиться. В свое время на этот проект была установлена библиотека PHPExcel. В библиотеке было требование - установить `mbstring.func_overload = 2`. Я сделал это и забыл совсем. И вот решил сделать тест системы через API битрикса. Он сказал, что есть ошибка и нужно то самое значение вернуть на 0. Я это сделал, но все равно поиск не заработал. И наконец, когда я случайно зашел на страницу товара в админке и сохранил его, не внося никаких изменений, - поиск стал его находить. Весь товар был залит при при `mbstring.func_overload = 2`, и когда я его заново перезалил - все заработало!